# Facebook don't see cookie status of HttpClient handler in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies, request, dotnet-httpclient

I'm make an request to login Facebook by using HttpClient class.
The result is "Cookies are not enabled on your browser. "
But, I assigned the HttpContainer to HttpClientHandler

```
    cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    handler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
                    UseCookies = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    UseProxy = true
                };
    httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

I use this code to login another pages, it work.

Why the Facebook tell me my Cookie is disabled ?

Comment: My guess is that Facebook is expecting you to send some cookie.

Comment: You right ! I need add cookies to the HttpClient handler bore request to facebook. ( Facebook require these cookie, other sites is not )